# Change div background on dytime basis

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, dst

I am having trouble changing my jumbotron background at specific day times, but nothing is showing and the jumbotron does not have any pictures as background.

**My Js:**

```
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 20) {
    if (document.getElementById("jumbotron")) {
        document.getElementById("jumbotron").background = "1.jpg";
    }
}else {
    if (document.getElementById("jumbotron")) {
        document.getElementById("jumbotron").background = "2.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: Look this sample https://jsfiddle.net/gevorgha/15baqpjt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use correct syntax:

```
document.getElementById("jumbotron").style.backgroundImage = "url('1.jpg')";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Full sample is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/gevorgha/15baqpjt/

Comment: Solved Thank you aber